# Printout problems on Bluej

Tags: java, bluej

I wanted to print a few programs for a school project on bluej. When I click the print button and set the paper size to A4 and give 'OK' the print comes in a weird small box. I tried increasing the font size. No changes happened. I also changed the page type to the different ones available, but no luck. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to solve your problem. The first is to copy-paste your code into another program, for example Word. The second way is to printscreen the code you want to print and then spread this picture across the A4. Maybe you should cut the edges off first.